# C:\Windows\system32\taskmgr.exe service cannot be started

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-error-reporting, system32

I killed some tasks on my laptop because my fan was to loud and everything is working, except some parts. I am not anymore administrator of my PC, so I cannot install nothing. My TaskManager doesn't work, error is **"The service cannot be started, either because it is disabled or because it has no enabled devices associated with it"**. When I try to run something from start->run, for example to run some services, regedit, gpedit.msc (that are some advice from other topics similar to this one) it doesn't work. For every task I got the same message:

**"The service cannot be started, either because it is disabled or because it has no enabled devices associated with it"**

I cannot use system restore, because I got the same error. (I found some option for use system restore - with ctrl+alt+del, and restart+shit down, but it is without point to the time where this happen).

Comment: Yes, it is the same

Comment: What does “killed some tasks” mean?

Comment: When TaskManager worked I selected in it and clicked End Process.

Comment: If that is all you did then a restart will fix the problem. So killing some tasks did not cause this problem.

Comment: Restart did not solve my problem. Maybe I also stopped some services. When I want to get in services, from start->services, I got same error

Comment: You took a hatchet to Windows and lopped-off some required organs. Use System Restore to rollback to a previous system restore point.

Comment: Please do a security scan with a good antivirus of your choice (not the one currently installed, please use online line scanners like https://www.eset.com/int/home/online-scanner/ -not a promo -) and make sure there is nothing caused due to infection.

Answer (score 1):

I really don't think you can cause this problem by just killing some tasks by using task manager.

I think task manager disabled from registry somehow.

To enable it you can try :

```
1. Click on Start button.

2. Type regedit in Start menu search.

3. Select registry editor in search.

4. in the Registry Editor browse for the following keys. 
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System
HKEY_USERS\.default\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System

5. Look for a DWORD value "DisableTaskMgr" in right-side pane. If you find it, delete it.

6. Now check if the Task Manager will be enabled.
```